# Как сохранить форматированный текст для веб-приложений и мобильных устройств?

Tags: sql, textformat

Я разрабатываю приложение, которое позволит терапевтам создавать задания-карточки для детей у которых наблюдаются языковые и речевые нарушения.

Такие карточки могут содержать просто текст или текст с изображениями. Задания затем должны отображаться в браузере и мобильном приложении.

Мой вопрос заключается в том, какой формат хранения заданий в бд лучше выбрать с учетом условий который я описал выше. Могу ли я хранить задания созданные врачом в виде HTML в бд или есть другие альтернативы.

P.S Меня особенно беспокоит отображение в мобильном приложении.

Comment: Хтмл с уменьшенным набором тагов.

Comment: да можете, но спец символы желательно хотя бы экранировать или лучше убирать из хранимых данных. конечно есть и альтернативы: BBcode и murkDown(это не формат а разновидность форматов). ну а какой лучше, это смотря в чем сравнивать. гуглите инфу по ним, собираете сравнительную таблицу и выбираете...